# Show Generated HTML on new page without saving in a file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have HTML generated from C# code dynamically, is there any way i can show this HTML in new page without saving in a file (increase clean-up cost).

```
var result = rg.GenerateHTML();
```

Comment: What type of application are you talking about? In a winforms application you can use a WebBrowser component to show un-saved HTML...

Comment: It's asp.net application. I can only find javascript window.open which need a file to be saved.

Comment: Press the F12 key on your browser

Comment: You can manipulate the DOM of the opened window without saving a file.

Comment: You could serve it using HTTP  have the browser open a new window with a url that triggers the C# ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using JavaScript method.

```
var win = window.open("", "Title", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=780, height=200, top="+(screen.height-400)+", left="+(screen.width-840));
win.document.body.innerHTML = "Pass your html here";
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Is there any other generic way of achieving that?

Comment: By generic, i mean "language independent"

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand language independent. JavaScript will work everywhere in web